# How exactly does the "weight" argument in PROC SUMMARY work?

Tags: sas

I have a piece of code which looks like this:

```
    proc summary data=a nway;
/*      class argang;      */
      class sex  / mlf;
     
      format sex konfmt.;
      weight kalvikt; 
      output out=a1(drop=_type_ _freq_  ) mean(&VAR)=&VAR  n(&VAR)=n ;  
    run;
```

I have a task which does not agree with PROC SUMMARY, which I will have to write manually (probably in PROC SQL). I will however still need to use the same weights, calculated the confidence intevals in a similar fashion etc.

So what exactly does the `weight kalvikt;` part do, if I had to replicate it? Intuitively each variable value should just be multiplied with "kalvikt" in order to arrive at the weighted value, but this is not clearly stated  in the documentation. It just says it "weigths" each variable value. It does not say exacly how the weighting is done.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0aq3hsvflztfzn1xa2wt6s35oy6.htm

Comment: It will probably not solve your problem, but `proc summary` is deprecated. SAS now promotes `proc means`.

Comment: @DirkHorsten They are the same program with different defaults for SUMMARY vs MEANS.

Comment: "task which does not agree with PROC SUMMARY" - what do you mean? explain, maybe it will help to give you some clues.

Comment: Links to see how weights are used in SUMMARY/MEANS: 1) https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0v0y1on1hbxukn0zqgsp5ky8hc0.htm 2) https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n1xkqt7u5ylr2kn11174pq11od76.htm#n0osbs4cchlvc6n136b1dkaw19gr

Comment: @yabwon I mean, sure. PROC SUMMARY (as I understand) is useful for analyzing the distribution of variable values in different groups. I work with dichotomous variables, so if we examine something like joint pain, this process can tell us 37 percent of all women report joint pain compared to 22 percent of all men, with a reported confidence interval. I need to do something much simpler. I need to find out which proportion of the observation belongs to certain categories (men, women, rural, urban) and calculate a confidence interval for "that".

Comment: @yabwon I did try using PROC SUMMARY for this but since the proportions of the subgroups added up to more than 100 percent I figured this wasn't the best process and that I was better of doing this manually.

Comment: Since you have dichotomous values, you should look at PROC FREQ, which also has a WEIGHT statement, and will calculate confidence intervals etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reference documentation [Base SAS Procedures Guide
Keywords and Formulas](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0v0y1on1hbxukn0zqgsp5ky8hc0.htm)

w<sub>i</sub> is the weight that is associated with x<sub>i</sub> if you use a WEIGHT statement. The base procedures automatically exclude the values of x<sub>i</sub> with missing weights from the analysis.

By default, the base procedures treat a negative weight as if it is equal to zero. However, if you use the EXCLNPWGT option in the PROC statement, then the procedure also excludes those values of x<sub>i</sub> with nonpositive weights. Note that most SAS/STAT procedures, such as PROC TTEST and PROC GLM, exclude values with nonpositive weights by default.

If you omit the WEIGHT statement, then w<sub>i</sub>, equals 1 for all i.

x̄ is the mean Σ w<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub> / Σ w<sub>i</sub>

Here is a picture of the variance formula with weight

[image]

The documentation further details the formulas of 18 descriptive statistics that SAS will compute, most which are directly or indirectly impacted by weight.